# setTimeout not delayed with an anonymous function

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, settimeout, anonymous-function

I'm building a custom slideshow for a project written with jQuery. Each slideshow has 4 events bound to it (play, stop, next, prev). The controls appear on mouseover over and mouseout. On mouseout I want a delay in the controls disappearing. To achieve this I used a setTimeout.

```
$(this).attr('timeout', setTimeout((function(obj){obj.fadeOut(250);})($(this)), 1000));
```

This is however causing a 'useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)' error

I removed the `($(this))` to see if I could simplify things.

```
$(this).attr('timeout', setTimeout((function(foo){alert(foo);})('bar'), 1000));
```

This caused 'bar' to be displayed in the alert message box on mouseout without a delay, or any errors reported in firebug. I can only assume by this logic that the anonymous function is being run right away which leaves nothing for the setTimeout to call later.

If I ignore the need to pass $(this) into the anonymous function and try

```
$(this).attr('timeout', setTimeout(function(){alert('foo');}, 1000));
```

everything works as expected, I must be doing something wrong with the syntax of the anonymous function but I'm out of ideas as to what it might be.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, just use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set the call contenxt, like this:

```
$(this).attr('timeout', 
  setTimeout($.proxy(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(250); }, this), 1000));
```

Note though this isn't a valid attribute, it's better to store things like this in [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), like this:

```
$(this).data('timeout', 
  setTimeout($.proxy(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(250); }, this), 1000));
```

Or this:

```
$.data(this, setTimeout($.proxy(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(250); }, this), 1000));
```

---

The problem with your current method is that this is self-invoking:

```
(function(foo){alert(foo);})('bar')
```

Where you want to return a function with the right context...more concisely done with [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) above in your case.